# How to print the text inside "< a href" tag, under li element?

Tags: webdriver

There are several li classes , which have "a href" tags. I want to print and save the names inside these tags. Example

```
<li class="first">
<a href="#" rel="1">Will and Mary</a>

/*

*String group1 = driver find class first . driver find li element . driver get the text inside a tag

*Print group1 

*/
```

I am using JAVA to write my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Use below logic to get the all texts which is inside li>a

```
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li.first>a"));
for(WebElement each:elements)
{
      System.out.println(each.getText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh ,
It worked, but how it works, could you please explain?
Suppose we have we have elements lies in class's sub class then how we gonna get it. Example :
    <ul class="drop down">
       <li class="first">
          <a href="#" rel="1">Will and Mary</a>
       <li class="second">
          <a href="#" rel="1">Mike and Michelle</a> 
...
...
...
</ul>

Comment: @user2172723: There's plenty of documentation out there on the getText() method of the WebElement class which will explain this for you.